# Where does the actual decryption of the recipient stealth address occur?

Tags: mining, transaction-confirmation

I want to find out where in the code an output of Alice's transaction becomes Bob's money.

Alice has 10 XMR, and she sends Bob 2 XMR, the tx looks like this -

OUTPUT:

```
#recipient output:

first output: amount->2 , stealth address -> Bob's address

#change output:

second output: amount->3 , stealth address -> Alice's address

third output: amount->5 , stealth address -> Alice's address
```

Miner starts mining, finds the tx and stores it on the blockchain. Where exactly in the code does the decryption of Bob's stealth address that makes the money go to Bob's wallet?

Comment: What do you call a stealth address ?

Answer (score 1):

[wallet2::scan_output](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/77e1ebff26aeb1466a79f2535b66f165c62468ab/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L1297) is probably what you're looking for as this checks if any of the tx outs are for this wallet. Then you can [see here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/77e1ebff26aeb1466a79f2535b66f165c62468ab/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L1557) where it stores to wallet.